# What's a safe way to do one-off initialization in Django/mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, initialization, mod-wsgi

I'm building a Django app that is designed to be multithreaded but reside in a single process running under mod_wsgi.  At start of day I need to do various, possibly-lengthy, initialization tasks such as loading a cache of data from the database into a quick lookup dict.  I need the intialization to run exactly once before any requests are handled and then to kick off a background thread to periodically update the loaded data.

I've tried putting the initialization code inline in a module but I've found that sometimes (if I put load on the server when it's starting) the init code gets executed more than once, screwing everything up.

Is there a good place to hook into Django or WSGI to run such init code exactly once before any requests are allowed in?  Alternatively, does anyone know under what situations module init code gets executed more than once (particularly in djangp/WSGI-land) or of a good way to stash an "i'm already initialized flag" somewhere?

Comment: Can you confirm first whether you are using embedded mode or daemon mode of mod_wsgi. I will then explain the appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: Seems like OP abandoned the question. Could you please explain how to do this appropriately when using embedded mode?

Comment: I'm using Daemon mode because I need all my state to be in one process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my initialization code in a middleware that is called when the first request is served.

After the initialization is done, you can raise a MiddlewareNotinuse exception, which causes Django not to execute that middleware again.

Remember that because of the way apache and http work, no code will be executed before the first request arrives.

Comment: Doing it in a middleware with the way that Django recommends WSGI application should be set up will delay the first request. What is really required is for it to be done at process start before any request actually handled. When OP actually clarifies their configuration can explain the appropriate way of doing that.

Comment: I'm using Daemon mode because I need all my state to be in one process.

Comment: Using middleware seems like the Django way of doing things.

Comment: does not work... I have a django - mod_wsgi - apache server; middleware __init__ gets called for every process apache spawns this is  of course because apache spawns a process per request... and each process runs all imports + other initializations... I did not find any other way to do this but use persistent memory(i.e. write to a file that we have Initialized...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an good old lockfile is a solution for this problem. Not a really elegant solution, but it saves you a lot of headaches in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have my initialization code called from the Settings.py file. The Settings.py file will only be executed once and is executed before any request is handled.

See http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings for ideas about splitting up the Settings.py file.

Comment: The Django settings file can actually be imported more than once and so that isn't a good place to put stuff. Read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html'.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the link in your comment is broken. I know that settings can be (and frequently are) loaded (imported) more than once, but there are multiple techniques to avoid executing code every time settings are loaded, like guarding some code with an `if` statement with some clever test. Are these worth using?

Comment: Just remove the trailing quote that is added. It is not possible to go back and edit such old comments. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html